# Ethereum data query

Tags: contract-development, transactions

Hi I would like to know how to perform SQL like queries using solidity? I want to write a Dapp that records a string transaction, say, a user name each time. Also I want to be able to look up whether this username exists on the Ethereum blockchain. I know I can easily use any database system. However I want my app to be able to run on Ethereum itself. What is the correct way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**There us no sql-like queries**.
 To store  your data you could use a `mapping` which is similar to a hashtable (key/value storage) or an `array` or just a simple variable (with set/get) : read the doc [here](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/introduction-to-smart-contracts.html). Every contract has its own storage which is theoretically unlimited (you should just be aware of the storage cost).

e.g of mapping use :

```
mapping(uint=> string) username; // a map linking each user(which is a string) with a key(which is a uint).
```

to store the desired username just provide its key. E.g:

```
uint i=1;
username[1]="yanguri";
```

so you guess it to retrieve your username use `username[1]`.

**Additional information** :
read about the differenece between Array an Mapping http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/introduction-to-smart-contracts.html

Comment: hi thanks for the information. Looks like mapping is the way to go.